# Witcher 2 starting gold

Tags: the-witcher-2

I just passed the siege part and noticed that I have over 3000 orens in my inventory. Anyone knows where they might have come from?

List of what choices I did:

> Suggested that amulet is unlucky. Missed the shot. Spared Aryan, who later torched the castle.

Comment: Did you import a Witcher 1 Save file?

Comment: Yes, but I've started playing Witcher 2 three times now always importing the same file and there were no gold before.

Comment: maybe a patch did it?

Answer (score 1):

It's from importing your Witcher 1 save file... if they didn't come in from before it was likely just something that needed to be patched and now awkwardly is working again.